# How to compare two statistic data array dynamically?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

right now I want to create a function to compare between two data statistics which is called as `statisticsComparator` and it will accept 2 parameters which is the `left_stat` and `right_stat`.

Those `key`s in both statistic data can be similar or have a slight differences.

This is what I already tried to make so far:

```
private static function statisticsComparator($left_stat, $right_stat)
{
    foreach (self::STATS_DATABASE as $key => $field) {
        $left_stat_field    = json_decode($left_stat->$field, true);
        $right_stat_field   = json_decode($right_stat->$field, true);

        $count_left_stat_field = count($left_stat_field);
        $count_right_stat_field = count($right_stat_field);

        // Choose
        if ($count_left_stat_field <= $count_right_stat_field) {
            foreach ($count_left_stat_field as $field) {

            }
        } else {
            foreach ($count_right_stat_field as $field) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the example of the stats data:
[image]

I want to make this function as dynamically as possible, I'm using `Laravel 5.8` Please help, thank you.